# Expand array with preferred default

Tags: ruby, arrays, default-value

The documentation for [Array#[]=](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) notes that

> If indices are greater than the current capacity of the array, the
>   array grows automatically.

When it does grow automatically, it does so with `nil` values:

```
arr = []
arr[2] = "!"
arr # => [nil, nil, "!"]
```

Is it possible to specify what the default is for those first two values?

Currently, I'm doing

```
arr = []
index = 2
currently_uninitialized_value_range = (arr.length)...(index)
default_values = currently_uninitialized_value_range.map{ "" }
arr[currently_uninitialized_value_range] = default_values
arr[index] = "!"
arr # => ["", "", "!"]
```

Which is a little verbose.

I'm using an array, rather than a hash, because they're representing the values I'm going to be inputting into a spreadsheet, and the library I'm using (Axlsx) prefers to have data added row by row.

Comment: `arr = Array.new(2, '') # => ["", ""]; arr[2] = "!"; arr => ["", "", "!"]`. At least if you only want to initialize the first n elements.

Comment: @BernardK `Array.new(2), { '' }` is safer than `Array.new(2, '')`. See "common gotchas" in the rdoc for [Array.new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-c-new).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array#fill`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-fill) might be your ticket.

```
arr = []

index = 2
arr.fill( "", arr.length...index )
arr[index] = "!"
# => ["", "", "!"]

index = 5
arr.fill( "", arr.length...index )
arr[index] = "!"
# => ["", "", "!", "", "", "!"]

index = 1
arr.fill( "", arr.length...index )
arr[index] = "!"
#=> ["", "!", "!", "", "", "!"]
```

Comment: Important: Array#fill will replace existing data as well. So starting at arr.length is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

What about using hash as array? It might look like this:

```
h = Hash.new do |hash,key|
  0.upto(key) { |i| hash[i] = "" unless hash.has_key?(i) }
end

h[5]
h[0] #=> ""
h[4] #=> ""
h.keys #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Maybe this approach require some additional tweaks to satisfy your demands, for example you can define method `size` and so on.

P.S. Get an array

```
h.values #=> ["", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

Comment: How would you pass values from this hash to a library's method that requires an array of values?

Comment: How about defining method to_a which will bring required format?

Answer (score 1):

I had a rapid look to the `Array` documentation and I didn't find nothing useful for this...

...but if I understood well you need to replace `nil` values with empty strings (`""`) before to export your data to the spreadsheet. What about call `to_s` on each element of the array before do that?:

```
arr.map! &:to_s
```